# Non-EU drivers license in the EU (ie. Spain)

Tags: europe, driving-licenses

I have a valid South African drivers license and will be travelling to Spain (and other EU countries), where I would be driving.

Will my South African license suffice?
Would I need to get an international drivers license (if yes, is this a long process?)

Comment: How long do you intend this trip to last, and where are you normally resident?

Comment: About a week in Spain.  Currently residing in the UK  (Italian passport).

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how long have you been resident in the UK?

Comment: Less than a year

Comment: Forgive the probing, but you've really *been resident* less than a year?  Not just "*it's been less than a year since I last left the UK*"?

Comment: I've been in the UK less than a year my whole life.  Since first ever arriving in the UK.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for probing.  Finally, is your South African licence the old book-style, or the new credit-card style one?

Comment: The new credit card style.  Also was planning on converting it to the UK but that takes ~3 weeks.

Comment: Well, that torpedoes the answer I was half-way through writing.  For non-EU licences, I believe it's up to each individual country which kinds of foreign licence they accept, and for how long, which means we'd need to see a full itinerary to be able to answer.  My strong advice, if you've been resident in the UK for at least 185 days, is to go ahead and exchange, and if that means holding off a couple of weeks on your holiday plans, I'd do so.

Comment: @MadHatter You're correct but I also think that exchanging the license does not in principle change anything.

Comment: @Relaxed I'm fairly sure it does.  [EU driving licences *must* be honoured, as they stand, for extended periods of time, in all EU countries](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm), as a treaty matter.  A UK licence is still an EU licence; it remains so whatever happens on Thursday, though depending on what does happen, it may not remain so for many more years :( .

Comment: @MadHatter All this is not defined in the treaties but in a directive. And what I recalled is that driving licenses obtained in exchange of a non-EU driving license are treated differently. The website you linked to confirms this (see the section on “Recognition of EU driving licences issued in exchange for a non‑EU licence”) but apparently it's only if you move to another country that this matters, not for short visits.

Comment: @Relaxed and the directives are honoured as a treaty matter.  My point is that, in the case of EU licence recognition, this is not an area where individual member states retain competence to legislate independently.  So if the OP exchanges his licence for a UK licence, as he is entitled to do, he can then drive around Europe  without having to worry about the acceptability of his licence on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @MadHatter Well, yes, they are, as I just told you and as your own source confirms. I don't know if we really need to discuss this further as it doesn't matter for the OP (and my initial comment was wrong in this respect) but exchanging a non-EU license in one EU country does not make it fully equivalent to a proper EU license. Also, the very existence of the EU obviously derives from the treaties so if you include secondary law under that phrase, “as a treaty matter“ really doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Relaxed as the page on Europa makes clear, the only substantive difference betwwen an EU licence obtained by testing in an EU country, and those obtained by exchange of an outside-EU licence, is that the latter cannot necessarily be exchanged for other EU licences if the holder **moves** to another EU country.  Other than that they **are** equivalent, and my point remains, so it **does** matter to the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41363/discussion-between-relaxed-and-madhatter).

Answer (score 5):

For Spain, according to [spain.info](http://www.spain.info/en/informacion-practica/consejos-viaje/consejos-practicos/conducir_en_espana/#r4):

> If you are the citizen of an EU member state, Switzerland, Norway,
>   Iceland or Liechtenstein: you only require your valid driver’s
>   license. If you are from another country you will require an
>   International Driver’s License.

The IDP is just a translation of the license; the one I got had labels in French, Arabic and English; even though the actual license has labels in English as well. I was traveling to Malaysia and it turned out the IDP was unnecessary.

It is normally not a long process - these are offered by auto clubs. You have to supply your current license and a fee. Sometimes they may ask for another form of ID.  I received mine in 15 minutes.

You may still be subject to additional rules and restrictions based on the local laws. For example, you may be entitled to drive a large vehicle but there may be an age restriction where you are visiting. Be mindful of these laws/variations as you are assuming complete liability when getting behind the wheel.

---

Given the above, from a practical standpoint I have had many friends (with non-EU, but digital licenses) that have rented cars and drive in Spain with out a IDP.

Since an IDP is so simple and relatively cheap to acquire (vs. a fine or worse in Spain), I would get it.

Comment: This might be true in Spain (no idea, although without any source I rather doubt that claim), but is definitely false for the whole EU. For example you are not allowed to drive with an American driver's license in Austria [see here](http://austria.usembassy.gov/res_motor.html). You're required to have an international driver's license or need an official translation by the Austrian Automobile Associations.

Comment: I think the website you quote confuses citizenship and country where the license was issued.